# Invalid syntax error during compile of bytes sequence

Tags: python, python-2.5

I've come across some old Python code (Python bytecode 2.5) that I've decompiled with uncompyle6. I've made no changes to the uncompiled code. I went to compile the code again in it's Python 2.5 environment I get this.

```
String = b'\xb8\xcd\xc2\x93\x8e\x8e\x94'
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm new to Python and wanted to have a look at the code. Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect that the `b` prefix for bytestrings didn't exist back in 2.5 - I think that was added sometime around 2.7, in preparation for Python 3.  Just remove the `b`.

Comment: @jasonharper 's memory seems accurate. I still have 2.7.16. It works fine there.

Comment: "Any ideas?" yes, don't use Python 2.5. Not if you are new to Python, not if you are maintaining ultra legacy applications, never ever use Python 2.5 now or in the future.

Comment: @jasonharper you were correct! Thanks.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Will do!

Answer (score 0):

b prefix is absent in Python 2.5 and older (it is equivalent to a plain string of 2.x, while plain string of 3.x is equivalent to a literal with u prefix in 2.x).